# Android сравнение введенных данных с базой данных

Tags: android, sql, button, retrofit

Есть активити, на нём есть поле "введите вашу страну" и при вводе страны, и нажатии кнопки, надо проверить настоящая ли страна, данные стран уже загружены в базу, но не пойму как сделать сравнение, подскажите, заранее спасибо!

Курсор:

```
public List<Countries> getAllCountriesQuery() {

    Cursor cursor = database.query(CountriesColumns.TABLE_COUNTRIES, null , null, null,
            null, null, null);

    List<Countries> list = new ArrayList<>();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Countries countries = new Countries();
        countries.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CountriesColumns.KEY_NAME));

        list.add(countries);
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
```

Ретрофит, получаю данные.

```
   Retrofit.getCountries(new Callback<List<Countries>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Countries> countries, Response response) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Данные загружены");

            for (Countries country : countries){
                DBCountriesMaster.getInstance(RegistrationActivity.this).addCountry(country);
            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Данные записаны в БД");

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Кнопка:

```
     btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String upperChar = "([A-Z])";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(upperChar);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(etPassword.getText().toString());

            if (etLogin.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } else if (etPassword.getText().length() <= 5) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is too short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (!matcher.find()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must have at least one big letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (etCountry ){

            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Нажали кнопку Submit");
        }


    });
```

Comment: Ну так а в чём проблема? Сделайте запрос в БД на предмет наличия страны с таким названием..

Comment: А зачем так заморачиваться, да и пользователю жизнь осложнять с вводом страны. Поставь просто выпадающии список стран, и чтобы пользователь мог выбрать свою страну. И сравнивать не надо просто достаешь, то значение, которое выбрал пользователь

Comment: Так вот я ж и спрашивал, как сделать этот запрос в БД, я не понимаю, а насчет выпадающего списка не пользовался, поищу.

Comment: android spinner или сюда загляни http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php